# How do I invoke a GNU make macro created using define?

Tags: makefile, macros, gnu

Is there any difference in the two ways GREP is invoked in my Makefile?  Any reason I should use one or the other?  Both seem to produce the same result.

```
define GREP
$(word 3,$(shell echo "#define  FOO     0xfff00100"))
endef

all:
        @echo $(GREP)
        @echo $(call GREP)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The way you are using it, there is no difference.  However, if your GREP macro were a function that took parameters, you would have to use $(call) to pass parameters to it.  For example:

```
define GREP
$(shell grep $1 $2)
endef

FOO:=$(call GREP,abc,words.txt)
```

This causes `$1` to be replaced with "abc", and `$2` with "words.txt".

See more in the GNU make manual on user-defined functions here:  http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Call-Function