# Use .PHONY targets as variables in Makefile

Tags: docker, makefile

I have a Makefile with several commands that are almost the same except for the parameter `SCRIPT`, which takes the same value of the target:

```
.PHONY: create run

create:
    docker build -t yoyo --build-arg SCRIPT=create . \
    && docker run -v ${HOME}/.aws/credentials:/root/.aws/credentials:ro yoyo

run:
    docker build -t yoyo --build-arg SCRIPT=run . \
    && docker run -v ${HOME}/.aws/credentials:/root/.aws/credentials:ro yoyo
```

What I would like to do is to convert the target that I pass through the command line into a variable so that I can have my Makefile like:

```
.PHONY: create run

$target:
    docker build -t yoyo --build-arg SCRIPT=$target . \
    && docker run -v ${HOME}/.aws/credentials:/root/.aws/credentials:ro yoyo
```

Is this possible somehow? If not, is there any similar way to simplify my Makefile? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a more fruitful approach is to encapsulate the command itself in a function.

```
define yoyo
 docker build -t yoyo --build-arg SCRIPT="$1" . && \
 docker run - ${HOME}/.aws/credentials:/root/.aws/credentials:ro yoyo
endef

.PHONY: create run

create:
    $(call yoyo,create)

run:
    $(call yoyo,run)
```

Building a Docker image with the same name with different functionalities depending on build configuration seems rather dubious, though. Perhaps it would make sense to build with different tags, just once?

```
.PHONY: create run
create run: %: .%-tagged
    docker run --rm - ${HOME}/.aws/credentials:/root/.aws/credentials:ro yoyo-$*

.%-tagged: Dockerfile
    docker build -t yoyo-$* --build-arg SCRIPT=$* .
    touch $@
```

Comment: (Notice that Stack Overflow renders tabs as spaces, so you won't be able to copy/paste this directly into your `Makefile`.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What kind of macro is this? If I google 'makefile macros' the macros seem different from this one

Comment: Yeah, I guess it's properly called a user-defined function. I just googled quickly to remind myself of the precise syntax and landed on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169143/how-do-i-invoke-a-gnu-make-macro-created-using-define

Comment: It is worth knowing that user-defined functions are a GNU extension.  GNU `make` is pretty common these days, but not ubiquitous.  Other `make`s do not support this.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that jumps out at me is that you're rebuilding your image just to run a different script.  You shouldn't need to do that.  You can pass an additional command to [`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/) after the image name, and this will replace the `CMD` shown in the Dockerfile.  I'll assume it's straightforward to remove the `ARG` and update your `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT` accordingly.

That means you need one rule to build the image:

```make
DOCKER_TAG := latest
DOCKER_IMAGE := yoyo:$(DOCKER_TAG)
# This rule should depend on any generated files that get COPYed in
.docker-build:
        docker build -t $(DOCKER_IMAGE) .
        touch "$@"
```

Then your rules to execute the image can depend on that.  You can also use additional Make variables to reduce the repeated parts.

```make
AWS_CREDENTIALS_FILE := $(HOME)/.aws/credentials
DOCKER_RUN_OPTS := -v $(AWS_CREDENTIALS_FILE):/root/.aws/credentials:ro

.PHONY: create run

create: .docker-image
        docker run $(DOCKER_RUN_OPTS) $(DOCKER_IMAGE) create

run: .docker-image
        docker run $(DOCKER_RUN_OPTS) $(DOCKER_IMAGE) run
```

This creates a hidden file `.docker-image` that records that the image has been built, but since there's a rule to "build" that file (by building the Docker image and `touch`ing it) it can be used as an ordinary dependency.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The rebuild was because I was making also COPY $SCRIPT.py ./ and not only modifying the CMD. But I guess it's even better to mount both files (run.py and creat.py) as volumes in any case

Comment: `COPY` both files in (and make them dependencies of the `.docker-image` target).  An additional shell script will add almost nothing to the image size.  Don't inject the code you actually want to run with a bind mount, make the image be self-contained.

Comment: Ok gotcha. I have some difficulties understanding your answer though. Where does it go the first code snippet? In which file? Why would you have AWS_CREDENTIALS_FILE variable at all? Is for making it more readable and not having such a long line below? Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Both go in the same Makefile.  `AWS_CREDENTIALS_FILE` is something you could reasonably want to override at deploy time (along with `DOCKER_TAG` or maybe `DOCKER_IMAGE`).

Comment: I am struggling to make the Dockerfile part works with your solution. Could you help me, please? Previously I was assigning ARGs value to ENVs and the CMD was CMD ["sh", "-c", "python3 ./${SCRIPT}.py ${ARGUMENT}"] I don't know how to pass the 'create' correctly to the CMD. Thank you very much and sorry for bothering

Comment: Anything after the image name in `docker run` replaces that `CMD`; `docker run $(DOCKER_IMAGE) ./create.py --option`.

Comment: Thanks. I get an error doing that:
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: exec: "./create.py": permission denied: unknown.
I have tried also with "python3 ./create.py" and I get another error:
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: exec: "python3 ./create_file.py": stat python3 ./create_file.py: no such file or directory: unknown.
I have done chmod 700 create.py but the error persists. How could I solve it? Thanks

Comment: This is arguably the way to go, but your question doesn't contain enough information about what's in the `Dockerfile` and what you hope to actually achieve. Probably (upvote, or even accept this answer and) ask a new question with enough information about your new problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
TARGETS := $(sort $(MAKECMDGOALS)) # remove duplicates
.PHONY: $(TARGETS)

$(TARGETS):
    docker build -t yoyo --build-arg SCRIPT=$@ . \
    && docker run -v ${HOME}/.aws/credentials:/root/.aws/credentials:ro yoyo
```

I question the usefulness of such a makefile however. If you write it as normal script you take away one level of complexity for the programmer coming after you.

Comment: Thanks! What do you mean with 'as normal script'?

Comment: Probably "write a shell script instead of a `makefile`."

Comment: @tripleee yes, a shell script. The required functionality seems not to profit from evaluating a dependency hierarchy, as there is no hierarchy. A loop would suffice from my understanding, and it has the POLS property.